# Add extra row to total but only for one product

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I want to add one extra row on the total of Shopping cart and checkout pages but only for one product when that product will be in the shopping cart.

**My requirement is to add the fixed shipping price for only one product that will be plus with other shipping if that product is in the cart.**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: You'll just have to make a conditional flag that checks something unique about that product and add a line ...

Comment: I have a SKU of product to add that but how I can add and code?? @NibbCNoble